# cURL proxy treated as a phishing Website

Tags: php, facebook, curl

I have seen many proxies being able to reach Facebook without any warning from the Antivirus.
Why does this code below (which is working) is treated as a Phishing Website for Antivirus like Kaspersky?

```
<?php
$header = NULL;
$url = "http://www.facebook.com";
$cookie = NULL;
$ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, $header);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, $header);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $cookie);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);;
curl_exec($ch);
?>
```

Thanks in advance.

PD: Antivirus isn't showing any warning for Twitter though.

Comment: what is the response of `ping www.facebook.com`

Comment: Website is working fine if I click the Antivirus to ignore it. ======>

Pinging star.c10r.facebook.com [31.13.64.7] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 31.13.64.7: bytes=32 time=70ms TTL=244

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not because of the code. It's because of the URL that is loading the code.

This one is giving me the "Phishing warning":

```
http://127.0.0.1/proxy/?url=http://facebook.com
```

However, a more trusted site with **https** doesn't give any warning from the AntiVirus.

```
https://127.0.0.1/proxy/?url=http://facebook.com
```